# Myetherwallet, how can I find my Ethereum lost?

Tags: go-ethereum

October 30, 2017 at myetherwallet

He participated in the Gladius Free Sale.

The quantity that you participated in was 37 ETH ...

But the ETH said the did not arrive at the Gladius Free Sale.

Unfortunately my Ethereum is still not coming back.

Myetherwallet does not accept e-mail.

I do not respond if I ask on Facebook or Twitter.

How can I find 37ETH?

mywallet :0x091597625737bc14e56D9f0f28b85F1Bb7a82e5d

my E-mail: xmmx@hanmail.net

Please.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your address on Etherscan.io, I have found the transaction that you are referring to - https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4bffa04f2cb2ce6f9c51cc0eee627919c05ffe057abcfb67d91f5ae65f9d54fc

It looks like the transaction was not successful - so the Ether was sent back to your account:

[image]

As you can see the TX status was marked as "Fail" and there is also a not saying that "value transfer did not complete" i.e. no ETH was sent.

There are a lot of transactions on your account - including some for amounts that tally to more than the 37 ETH that you had originally intended to send to the Gladius token sale.

If you really want peace of mind, then I recommend going through the list of transactions as displayed on Etherscan and tallying them all up - I think that you will find that the ETH was returned, but you've spent it at a later date.

Comment: SteveJaxon. Thank you for your reply. I have done the calculations. Never did the ETH return.

Comment: I had calculated everything from the time the purse was created until the time it was shipped.